# what to put in javascript to know that i input a number?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

so i just learned javascript, and learning switch, so i want to know how if i input any number, the alert can know its a number, and the else is anything that not number

```
var thisVarA = +prompt('a?', '');

switch (thisVarA) {
    case 1:
        alert('you input number 1');
        break
    case 2:
        alert('you input number 2');
        break
    case 3:
        alert('you input number 3');
        break
    case 4:
        alert('ok this is more than enough');
        break
    default:
        alert('its not just a number');
}
```

so i want case 4 is if i put any number other than 1,2,3 the alert can know it and put ok its a number
and the else is anything than number even if its has a number ike milano1010

Comment: Use [Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a switch statement, this would be better for just an if statement.

```
if (!isNaN(thisVarA)) {
   alert('you input number ', thisVarA);
} else {
   alert('its not a number');
}
```

Here we do several things. `isNaN` checks if it is not a number. We use `!` before it to reverse that logic so now we check if it IS a number. The alert starts with 'you input number ' and fills in the number automatically with your variable number instead of needing to check each case. Else is anything that is not just a number like `milano1010`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements: (switch + determining whether the input is numeric):

```
<script>
 var thisVarA = +prompt('a?', '');

switch (true)  {
    case thisVarA==1:
        alert('you input number 1');
        break
    case  thisVarA==2:
        alert('you input number 2');
        break
    case  thisVarA==3:
        alert('you input number 3');
        break
    case Number.isNaN(thisVarA)==false:
        alert('ok its a number');
        break
    default:
        alert('it is anything than number');
}
 
 </script>
```

The Number.isNaN() function determines whether a value is an illegal number (Not-a-Number)

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight sublety in your set up as there is a + immediately in front of your prompt. Javascript takes this to be an arithmetic operation in this situation and therefore forces whatever you input to be of type 'number'. If it were not there the result of your prompt would not be forced to be of type number.

As it is, when you type something like abc123 it is forced to be a number, but it isn't one. Javascript in this situation will give it type 'number' but its value will be NaN (not a number).

Here's your switch with an alert to show you the type and under the default we check whether it's NaN or not.

```js
var thisVarA = +prompt('a?', '');

alert('The type is ' + typeof(thisVarA));

switch (thisVarA) {
    case 1:
        alert('you input number 1');
        break
    case 2:
        alert('you input number 2');
        break
    case 3:
        alert('you input number 3');
        break
    default:
        if (!isNaN(thisVarA)) {
           alert('you input number ' + thisVarA);
        }
        else {
           alert('its not just a number');
        }
}
```